# Check for spaces in perl using regex match in perl

Tags: perl, perl-module

I have a variable how do I use the regex in perl to check if a string has spaces in it or not ?  For ex:

```
$test = "abc small ThisIsAVeryLongUnbreakableStringWhichIsBiggerThan20Characters";
```

So for this string it should check if any word in the string is not bigger than some x characters.

Answer (score 6):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $test = "ThisIsAVeryLongUnbreakableStringWhichIsBiggerThan20Characters";
if ( $test !~ /\s/ ) {
    print "No spaces found\n";
}
```

Please make sure to read about regular expressions in Perl.

[Perl regular expressions tutorial - `perldoc perlretut`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html)

Answer (score 3):

You should have a look at [the perl regex tutorial](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html).  Adapting their very first "Hello World" example to your question would look like this:

```
if ("ThisIsAVeryLongUnbreakableStringWhichIsBiggerThan20Characters" =~ / /) {
    print "It matches\n";
}
else {
    print "It doesn't match\n";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
die "No spaces" if $test !~ /[ ]/;        # Match a space
die "No spaces" if $test =~ /^[^ ]*\z/;   # Match non-spaces for entire string

die "No whitespace" if $test !~ /\s/;     # Match a whitespace character
die "No whitespace" if $test =~ /^\S*\z/; # Match non-whitespace for entire string
```

Answer (score 0):

To find the length of the longest unbroken sequence of non-space characters, write this

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use List::Util 'max';

my $string = 'abc small ThisIsAVeryLongUnbreakableStringWhichIsBiggerThan20Characters';

my $max = max map length, $string =~ /\S+/g;

print "Maximum unbroken length is $max\n";
```

**output**

```
Maximum unbroken length is 61
```